# How to install updated version of HTML tidy

Tags: software-installation

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr), `tidy` is very old:

```
$ tidy --version
HTML Tidy for Linux released on 25 March 2009
$
```

What's the easiest way to get [tidy-html5](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5) installed?

Have I somehow overlooked the package for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### From source

Follow the instructions at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5). For the prerequisites, I needed to:

```
sudo apt-get install -y cmake xsltproc
```

### Package install

Here's what I did to move from the current `apt-get install tidy` to the latest version.

1. Find the URL of the latest version to download at: http://binaries.html-tidy.org.

   Try the `linux 64-bit DEB` first if you're not sure which to pick.
2. Download it:

   ```
   wget <LATEST URL>
   ```
3. Remove unneeded `tidy-lib` package. `tidy-lib` is included in the `.deb` you just downloaded.

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y autoremove tidy
   ```
4. Install the `.deb` you just downloaded:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb
   ```
5. Clean up:

   ```
   rm tidy-*.deb
   ```

Thanks to @Anwar for pointing me in this direction.

### Troubleshooting

I needed to do `hash -d tidy` to get bash to run the new version from `/usr/local` after I installed from source. You also may need to do this if you chose to keep the previous package of `tidy`.

Comment: If you install a latest version, older one will be automatically replaced. you don't need to remove it

Comment: If I don't remove first I get `dpkg: error processing archive tidy-5.2.0-64bit.deb (--install):` `trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libtidy.so', which is also in package libtidy-0.99-0 20091223cvs-1.2ubuntu1.1`

Comment: You accepted my answer, then wrote your own answer saying it didn't work in Linux mint, unaccepted after some days, then again accepted. Again unaccepted. Why?

Comment: Sorry - I don't know why it was unaccepted twice. I didn't intentionally unaccept it in the last 2 days if that's what you're asking. Perhaps it was part of the edit process I did just now. I'm accepting this answer over yours because deals with `overwrite '/usr/lib/libtidy.so'` and shows where to get the latest version.

Comment: Tom Hale, first link in your answer is dead and I can't find archive copy of it in Internet Archive and archive.is. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Updated.

Answer (score 12):

You can install the latest html-tidy from source using the instruction given on its [github page](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/tree/master/README).

But the easiest way to install the latest version of html-tidy5 would be downloading the latest binary from this page http://binaries.html-tidy.org/

If you're using 64bit Ubuntu, you'd do basically these commands

```
wget https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/releases/download/5.4.0/tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb
sudo dpkg -i tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb
```

It should be installed fine.

Comment: [**Errors were encountered while processing**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaPelicanTest/jobs/348594495#L469). Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, you should uninstall the original tidy package before installing that one.

Answer (score 2):

1. On the latest Ubuntus (Zesty, 17.04, and Artful, 17.10), it is updated to version 5.2.
2. There is a [backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/backports) for Trusty (14.04) and Xenial (16.04): `ppa:jonathonf/backports`
3. You could also use the nodejs package `html-validator-cli` as a workaround

   ```
   sudo -H npm install -g html-validator-cli
   html-validator --filename=path/to/file
   ```

   but it needs an internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Summary

Method [**from official documentation**](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/blob/next/README/BUILD.md).

**If** you need the latest CLI version, run in terminal:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install xsltproc
$ git clone https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5.git
$ cd tidy-html5
$ cd build/cmake
$ cmake ../.. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIB:BOOL=OFF
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

---

### 2. Relevance

This answer is relevant for April 2018. In the future, the data of this answer may be obsolete.

---

### 3. Demonstration

[**On Travis CI environment**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaTidyDebugging/builds/369680340).

---

### 4. Limitations

**Else** you need custom HTML Tidy things, you can need another options. [**Some citations**](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/721#issuecomment-383287814) of HTML Tidy contributor:

> If you are just going to use the console app `tidy`, which by default is linked with the static library `libtidys.a`, then not building and installing the shared library, `libtidy.so`, that is `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIB:BOOL=OFF`, is fine, but this is unusual in unix/linux…
>
> There are even some in the unix/linux community that **prefer** to build the console app tidy linking only with the **shared** library. See the cmake `-DTIDY_CONSOLE_SHARED:BOOL=ON` option, and see issue #326…
>
> And that also means to try to be consistent with the install location, like using `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX[:PATH]=/usr`, but as stated in most cases the cmake default is also fine… and usually does not represent a problem…

---

### 5. Additional links

- [**build HTML Tidy in different Operating Systems**](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/blob/next/README/BUILD.md)
- [**discussion about build from sources on HTML Tidy issue tracker**](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/721)