# tidy/libtidy recursive installation hell

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades, gdebi

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed "tidy" to process some HTML files. I discovered it was unable, did a little Googling, and found the "modern" version of tidy at  http://www.html-tidy.org/. I downloaded tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb and used `sudo gdebi tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb` to install it. All worked well, no problems. Except that every morning, the first time I run tidy, I get:

```
tidy: error while loading shared libraries: libtidy-0.99.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The only fix I know is `sudo apt-get remove tidy` and run the `gdebi` install again. Which works fine until the next morning. I imagine unattended upgrades are doing this to me. At first, I thought my mistake might have been installing the "old" tidy first -- maybe the `gdebi` command didn't quite fix everything up. But now I've reproduced the same problem on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 that has never had the "old" tidy installed, so I can't figure out why this doesn't bite lots of people.

I'm no package manager expert, so please let me know if there are commands that produce output with likely clues that I should have included here.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). Why don't you use the `tidy` package from the default software repositories? Is it missing a feature that you need?

Comment: It is renowned for being [years out of date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823258/how-to-install-updated-version-of-html-tidy). IME, it is nearly non-functional against a modern HTML page. I do not know the story of why the default repos are using such an out of date version rather than the [reborn](http://www.html-tidy.org/) 2017 version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](/q/18654/175814)