# Trouble installing HTML Tidy 5.4.0 on Xenial

Tags: software-installation

This pre-existing question on askubuntu.com purports to solve the problem of installing the reboot of HTML Tidy: [How to install updated version of HTML tidy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823258/how-to-install-updated-version-of-html-tidy). However, when I followed the accepted answer's instructions on Xenial 16.04.2, I encountered a problem that was not covered there, so am creating a new question.

I do the following:

```
wget https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/releases/download/5.4.0/tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb
sudo dpkg -i tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb
```

and get this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb (--install): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libtidy.so', which is also in package libtidy-0.99.0 2009 1223cvs-1.5
```

I do not already have the older tidy package installed, but I went through the motions of uninstalling it anyway:

```
sudo apt-get -y autoremove tidy
Package 'tidy' is not installed, so not removed
```

No change in ability to install tidy 5.4.0 afterwards, or the error message that ensues.

Here is the result of apt-cache policy:

```
apt-cache policy libtidy-0.99-0
libtidy-0.99-0:
  Installed: 20091223cvs-1.5
  Candidate: 20091223cvs-1.5
  Version table:
  *** 20091223cvs-1.5 500
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy libtidy-0.99-0` say?

Comment: Added apt-cache policy output above.

Comment: So it looks like the older tidy package *is* installed - but its name is `libtidy-0.99-0`

Comment: Aha. I was able to uninstall `libtidy-0.99-0` and then `sudo dpkg -i tidy-5.4.0-64bit.deb` worked, so problem solved. I think I should mention for posterity that uninstalling `libtidy-0.99-0` also uninstalled `python-utidylib`.